# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for Keycloak

Tags: java, post, http-post, httpurlconnection, keycloak

I am hitting the keycloak server through java application. When I run the url on postman along with the parameters, I am getting the response token but when I try to do the same through java, it is throwing the error. Below is my code:

```
    public void login() {
    try {
    String uri = "http://localhost:7080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token";
    URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setReadTimeout(10000);

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "SuperAdminPortal"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "admin"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "demo"));

                OutputStream oss = con.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(oss, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getQuery(params));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                oss.close();

                con.connect();
                con.getInputStream()
    } 
catch (Exception ex)
      {ex.printStackTrace();}
}


private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

I get the below error in the line "con.getInputStream()"

```
11:05:08,346 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6) java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:7080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Any information is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

It was still showing me the same error. I solved this by writing the below code:

```
String uri = "http://localhost:7080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token";

            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
            post.setHeader("User-Agent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
            List<BasicNameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "SuperAdminPortal"));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", useName));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line1 = "";
            while ((line1 = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line1);
            }
            System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Yeah. You have to send the parameters as form in the POST body. So post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters)); is doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
See [RFC-6749 OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-37).

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```